# Apache POI - How to set cell value as double with dot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 5.0.0 for write data to excel.
I try to set cell value as double like that format '11.33'

First one, I try to write value as double and set cell type as NUMERIC then Excel shows it '11,33'.

Second one, I try to write value as String and set cell type as STRING then Excel shows it '11.33', when double click to cell, excel change value to date and shows 'Nov.33'

I am using generic method for writing values to excel.
First one is

```
 else if (fieldClass == Double.class || fieldClass == double.class) {
        double value = (double)field.get(obj);
        cell.setCellValue(value);
        cell.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);}
```

Second one is

```
else if (fieldClass == Double.class || fieldClass == double.class) {
        double value = (double)field.get(obj);
        cell.setCellValue(value + "");
        cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
}
```

Comment: If Excel shows numeric values using comma as decimal separator, then your Excel application is set to use comma as decimal separator. The values in Microsoft Office files always are stored in en_US locale. So a numeric value always gets stored using dot as decimal separator. Only the applications may use different locales. So if you want to see dot as the decimal separator in Excel, then you have to set that in Excel application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use number formatter

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

cell.setCellValue(numberFormat.format(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to 2 decimal letters in excel you can use below code.

```
style.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00"));
```

This will make the value `0` show up as `0.00`, `11.33` as `11.33` and `12.4` as `12.40`

Comment: I tried this but still i got value with comma. I look the other format types and found a solution now. I cast double value to string and  format like this. cellStyle.setDataFormat((short)0x31);

Comment: Perfect 